# How can I deploy the django web application on apache in windows?

Tags: django, windows, apache

I want to deply the django web application on apache in windows. Howw can I do that step by step?

I have installed python and apache on windows. How can I config the apache to serve django web app? I deploy django web app on local host with out apache but i know that its not secure to server users on the web without web server.